# How to divide screen between two layers or nodes?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

NOTE: This is a different issue than other questions on stack overflow like:
[Split screen on Cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059842/split-screen-on-cocos2d)
Do not mark this as duplicate, as this has to do with two different Nodes. I am not trying to create two viewports for one node. What I am trying to do, is just manage two different nodes on screen.

I have two `CCNodes` (can change them to `CCLayers` if that would work better). I want each of them to occupy exactly half of the screen. Currently I place one at the bottom `(0,0)`, and the other half way up `(0, <screen height / 2>)`.

Each node contains child nodes, (landscape, sprites etc, such as the blue & red x's), representing actors in the game world. Each node represents a different view of the same world. For example, if this was a race, the top node would represent a camera following the red X, and the bottom node would represent a camera following the blue X.

**I don't want graphics of one node, overlapping in the area of the other node.**

By having the z-order of one node higher than the other, I can prevent the graphics from the lower node overlapping with the upper node. But how do I prevent the graphics from the upper node from overlapping with that of the lower node. I use z-order just as a sample possible solution, but the idea is that **if each node represents a cameras view of the world, how do I ensure that the each camera view occupies only half the screen?**

How do I do this? All kinds of things happen in each of these nodes (world gets rotated / zoom in / out etc). I need to be able to manipulate each of the nodes, but still not have them overlap (visibly) ?

**OK:**

[image: Split Screen view]

**OK:** The blue X does not overlap with the upper node's world.

[image: Split Screen view 2]

**Not OK:** The red X which is supposed to be part of the upper node, overlaps with the lower node.

[image: Split Screen view with overlap]

EDIT: This is a different issue than other questions on stack overflow like:
[Split screen on Cocos2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059842/split-screen-on-cocos2d)

I am not trying to view two parts of the same node. I am trying to divide the screen between TWO DIFFERENT NODES.

EDIT: It is not possible or scalable to try the viewport solution in my scenario. I need to divide the screen between two different nodes. I cannot use just one node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using cocos2d version 2.0 or higher, try a CCClippingNode as your root node for each 'camera view'. Basically, you can define a bounding rectangle, outside of which the clipping node will not display the node contents.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is as follows.

**Solution 1: Complex**

Assume these.

Layer Top z = 1;
Layer Bottom z = 0;

Case 1 : When a single node in any world crosses its boundary.
Just interchange their z orders. And it works fine.

Case 2 : When nodes in both layers cross their boundary
Check which world has max z value.
Make the overlapping chid invisible. Create a child node in the other layer(with less z value with same properties, and same physics values too As you are using box2d).

In case where a player is jumping in the lower layer, you have to synchronize both childs in top and bottom layers. So when it is coming down and overlapping vanishes, delete the child in the latter layer and again make the overlapped node visible.

Note : If you fail in case 1 yu can use case 2 but it is very complex

**Solution 2: Simple**
Assume these.
Layer Top z = 1;
Layer Bottom z = 0;

Case 1 : Interchange z orders

Case 2: Layer Top z = 0
Layer Bottom z = 1;

**Assuming the bottom layer has real player who is playing and top layer is for other player**

When a player in lower jumps, just reposition the layer downwards. So the it would be great to see the platform is moving according to the player's y position along with x position. t looks even more realistic.

Comment: Neither of your solutions are acceptable. In the first solution (case 2) you haven't accounted for the situation where a child node is half in each of the worlds. It is not acceptable to make the child invisible, when it should be visible. It is also a very messy solution. Also, its very likely that there may always be nodes crossing boundaries. Solution (2) does not solve the problem I asked for.